# c++ unable to read memory with custom class when calling a function

Tags: c++, class, pointers, memory

I am having problems running functions within a custom class. Here is my code:

ROBOTSTRUCTURE.H

```
#pragma once

#include "math.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
class RobotStructure
{
    bool faceTrackingEnabled;

public:
    RobotStructure();
    ~RobotStructure();
    bool testFunction(string input);
```

ROBOTSTRUCTURE.CPP

```
#include "RobotStructure.h"
RobotStructure::RobotStructure()
{
    faceTrackingEnabled = true;
}

RobotStructure::~RobotStructure()
{
}

bool RobotStructure::testFunction(string input)
{
    cout << input << endl; //THIS DOES NOT WORK, When using debugger shows that the entire class "Robot Structure" as unable to read memory
return true;
}
```

MAIN

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>

#include "RobotStructure.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    RobotStructure *mybot= new RobotStructure();
    mybot->testFunction("test");
    return 0;
}
```

If a set a breakpoint in main, my class is initialized correctly and everything is fine. As soon as a call the "test function" the class falls out of memory within the test function.

When it goes back to main just before return 0; the class is also out of memory. As if the pointer is deleted somehow. Can someone please explain what is happening and what did I do that is wrong?

Comment: Does ROBOTSTRUCTURE.CPP include iostream?

Comment: It'd also need `std::cout` and `std::endl` in that context, as presented.

Comment: You are not posting the same code as you are running. Posted code wouldn't compile. Provide an **exact** [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I just updated it to be exact. Please check it once more. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `testFunction` does not use any class members. If you compile this code with optimization enabled ("Release"-Configuration in VisualStudio, `-O2` on gcc), the compiler might render some variables (like `this`) "undebuggable".

Comment: Thank you. The issue was Code Optimization just as you suggested.!

Answer (score 1):

You declared the function as `bool testFunction(string input)` but the function is not returning anything. This leads to undefined behavior in C++.

In addition your example wouldn't compile (you declared an argument `input` but you are using `intput`).

Comment: this is just an example of the actual code which I simplified for the forums. I will edit it now so that it is clearer.

Comment: @Jack Being able not to return a value from function that are declared to return a value, is it compiler specific or does the c++ standard support it?

Comment: @bkVnet: the C++ doesn't allow a value-returning function to not returning anything. It's undefined behavior for the standard. It's not a compiler error because it's not always possible to analyze code flow to determine that nothing has been returned by a specific code path.

Comment: @Jack OK but when you say "it's not a compiler error", does it mean according to the standard. Because this code won't compiler on MS visual studio because the function is not returning a value.

Comment: @bkVnet: it means that it is not required by the standard to be a compiler error, but this doesn't mean that a compiler is not allowed to issue a warning about that problem.